# How to change the date format of maillog?

Tags: postfix, email-server, dovecot

The format of the dates of my maillog logs looks like this:

```
May 12 04:12:54
```

I need to include the year on this date. Is it possible to make this kind of change?

Answer (score 3):

After a little more research and some tests, I found the solution I need.
My server works with CentOS 7.6, which use rsyslog to log.

1. Edit the file /etc/rsyslog.conf and add the following template before the section "RULES":

```
$template MailLogFormat, "%timestamp:::date-year%-%timestamp:::date-month%-%timestamp:::date-day% %timestamp:::date-hour%:%timestamp:::date-minute%:%timestamp:::date-second% %hostname% %syslogtag%%msg:::sp-if-no-1st-sp%%msg:::drop-last-lf%\n"
```

2. Search for the line:

```
# Log all the mail messages in one place.
mail.*       -/var/log/maillog
```

and change to:

```
# Log all the mail messages in one place.
mail.*       -/var/log/maillog;MailLogFormat
```

3. Restart rsyslog:

```
systemctl restart rsyslog
```

Done. The logs in the /var/log/maillog file will be printed with the date in the format: Year-Month-Day Hour:Minute:Second

Comment: On Ubuntu my Postfix log file is `/var/log/mail.log` but for the rest it all works.

Answer (score 3):

A possibly better answer is to employ the newer syslog standard to all rsyslog generated logs.....see

```
 http://support.pimpmylog.com/kb/softwares/rsyslog-protocol-23-format
```

The configuration is quite close to the RFC 5424 standard.

This is done by putting the following line in your rsyslog.conf file:

```
 $ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_SyslogProtocol23Format
```

A given line in a syslog file would appear as follows:

```
 <27>1 2014-01-12T20:06:05.783312-05:00 somebody smbd 3752 - -  [2014/01/12 20:06:05.783190,  0] printing/print_cups.c:487(cups_async_callback)
```

Notice the full time and date are included as well as the TimeZone on the timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to dioo, the following worked for me in Ubuntu Server 20.04

1. Goto rsyslog conf

   `sudo nano /etc/rsyslog.conf`
2. Under Global Directives, comment out the existing style such as `$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat` and add the below line

> $template CustomFormat, "%timestamp:::date-year%-%timestamp:::date-month%-%timestamp:::date-day% %timestamp:::date-hour%:%timestamp:::date-minute%:%timestamp:::date-second% %hostname% %syslogtag%%msg:::sp-if-no-1st-sp%%msg:::drop-last-lf%\n"

3. Save and close the file. Goto the default-conf file in the below location

   `sudo nano /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`
4. Append "CustomFormat" after each log line you wish to change your timestamp

   `user.*                          -/var/log/user.log;CustomFormat`
5. Restart the service

   `sudo systemctl restart rsyslog`

The final timestamp is as follows

> 2020-12-22 22:50:19